# Codeigniter - Fetch data from many tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-schema

Hi I 'd like some help please.
I have 3 tables

```
**Products**
product_id //eg 1
product_name //eg apple imac
description // mplah mplah
category_id // 3 - desktops
...

**Features**
feature_id // 1
feature_name // processor
category_id // takes the parent-category eg computers with id = 1

and a pivot table **product_features** that should have something like this
product_id // 1
feature_id // 1
feature_value // intel i5
```

Each table also represents a model (so i have a product_model, feature_model and a product_feature_model -which i'm not sure yet if its needed-)

In my view I have a form in which i do inserting/editing, in which I want to fetch all the features of the specific category (in my example 'computers') and the values that also belong to the specific product.

So I should get something like 
*apple imac* - *processor* - *intel i5*,
*nikon* - *zoom* -  *12Mpx*

How can I make this query and in which model is it better to put into??

Here's the query i've tested in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT `features`.*, `product_features`.`value`
FROM (`features`)
LEFT JOIN `product_features` ON `features`.`feature_id`=`product_features`.`feature_id`
WHERE `features`.`category_id` =  1
WHERE `product`.`product_id` = 1 // without this, it returns  feature_id, feature_name, category_id and feature_value collumns, but I also want to specify from wich product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Product is your "primary" entity, so I would put it there

2) Use a MY_Model base model (you can Google it for CodeIgniter) for all your models

3) If you do 2, you'll want the join table model so you can make simple updates

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't thourough enough, I'm already using a MY_Model (http://codeigniter.tv/). I have also tried to do this with JOINS but when I'm trying to pass the product id I don't get any results back. see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select p.*, f.*, pf.* from Products p, Features f, product_features pf where p.product_id = pf.product_id AND pf.feature_id = f.feature_id AND p.category_id = f.category_id
```